# Error in get source code of an html page in C# .net

Tags: c#, html, .net, xml

I want to get all the source code of a site in C# .net with WebClient , 
i create a simple code in C# windows form 
i try another website it work correct but i need this website and I cant get it .
my code :

```
 using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
            {
                client.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
                client.Encoding = UTF8Encoding.UTF8;
                string htmlCode = client.DownloadString("http://www.feleziran.ir/products/milgerd");
                byte[] bytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(htmlCode);
                htmlCode = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
            }
```

when i use break point and get the view in xml show this message for htmlDode :

> The XML page cannot be displayed  Cannot view XML input using style
>   sheet. Please correct the error and then click the Refresh button, or
>   try again later.
>
> ---
>
> Invalid at the top level of the document. Error processing resource
>   'file:///C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Temp/VSD1.tmp.XML'...
>
> ? ^

is there any better way to do it ? how i can solve it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Html files may not always be a valid XML file. So you should never display it wit a XML viewer. Try to save it and open it with a browser instead.

```
 using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
 {
      client.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
      client.Encoding = UTF8Encoding.UTF8;
      string htmlCode = client.DownloadString("http://www.feleziran.ir/products/milgerd");
      System.IO.File.WriteAllText("c:\\htmlfile.html", htmlCode);

 }
```

Anyway for what you want to achieve, it's  not enough as you should parse every links in the html and download them as well.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't provided all the code, as iｔ appears you then save the htmlCode string to a temp file and then feeding the content to an XML viewer.

Anyway the issue is that the HTML downloaded from this particular website is HTML5 markups - and by definition HTML5 is not strictly XML-compliant. For example, it contains a line `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">` which won't be accpeted by XML parser.

So you may want to change how you view the downloaded HTML markups.

Besides, there is another issue in the code - you already get proper text  with `client.DownloadString` method and don't need the following two lines of code that changes it to `byte[]` then back to `string`.

Comment: so , never i cant do this ? is there any way to get the html code of page ?

Comment: you already have got the html code, you just can't use XML viewer to view it - use a simple TextBox instead.